# The title of Dr. rer. nat in my country

Tags: phd

I would like to ask a general question.

I graduated Dr. rer. nat from Germany in 2017. The question is, can I use title Dr. rer. nat. (in front of my name) in my country Malaysia ?

Thank you for your answers

SAB